# Calculation coefficients of compositions

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on practice problems for my combinatorics & optimization class and I'm having some issues figuring out how to approach a type of question. The textbook doesn't have any related examples and there aren't any answers, so I'm not sure what to do/if my thinking is correct.

The question asks to "Calculate the following coefficients:"

a) $[x^{8}](1-x)^{-7}$

b) $[x^{10}]x^{6}(1-2x)^{-5}$

c) $[x^{8}](x^3+5x^4)(1+3x)^{6}$

and so on. I listed 3 since they all have very different functions beside the exponent on the left. So my thinking was as follows:

The functions beside the $x$ in the bracket, call them $a(x), b(x), c(x)$ respectively, each form a generating series for some composition. So $a(x)$ is a composition with items from the set $A = \{1, 7, 49, 343, ...\}$ and $[x^8]$ represents the coefficient of $x^8$, ie I need to find the number of compositions that can be formed so that their sum adds up to 8 and so that each entry $c_i$ is in $A$. So the only possible compositions are $(1, 7)$ and $(7, 1)$, so the coefficient is 2.

Alternatively, still for a), I could take the approach wherein I try to find a recurrence relation, ie try to find some way to relate each term in the series $a(x)$. This I would do by seeing that $(1-x)^{-7} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^7}$ and $(1-7)^7 = 1 - 7x + 21x^2 - 35x^3 + 35x^4-21x^5+7x^6-x^7$ so for the coefficients $a_n$ in $a(x)$ one can find the recurrent relation $a_n = 7a_{n-1}-21a_{n-2}+35a_{n-3}-35a_{n-4}+21a_{n-5}-7a_{n-6}+a_{n-7}$ where $a_0 = 1$. Is this at all a correct way of going about it? If not, how should I approach this question?

That being said, I have no idea how to start b) and c). Using my approach above, with the recurrence relation, wouldn't seem to work since $b(x)$ has a numerator with a greater exponent than the denominator. Also, $c(x)$ isn't a fraction at all.

If anyone could please explain how to solve these questions/where my thinking goes wrong, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I am not an expert, but I thought the way to solve (a) & (b) is to use the formal equality ${1 \over 1-x} = (1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \dots)$.  As for (c), the RHS is just a regular polynomial you can expand and then find $[x^8]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) for all of these.  The first is
$$
[x^8](1-x)^{-7}=(-1)^8\binom{-7}{8}=(-1)^8\frac{(-7)(-8)\ldots(-14)}{8!}=\binom{14}{8}.
$$
This can be interpreted as the number of ways of writing $8$ as the sum of seven non-negative integers, but the combinatorial interpretation is not needed to solve the problem.  For the others, I would go directly to the binomial theorem, without trying to interpret.

Comment: So then, for b) would it be $(-2)^4\binom{-5}{4} = 1120$ and for c) $3^5\binom{6}{5}+5(3^4)\binom{6}{4} = 9558$?

Comment: That looks right, except for possible arithmetic error in (c).